# Publish Service Fabric for specific build configuration from VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, publish, azure-service-fabric

With the absolute plethora of configuration files, you'd think I could find this, but so far no luck.

I can publish to my cluster just fine.  I right-click on the fabric project, and select publish.  I then select the publish profile and I'm on my way.

The problem is that it always publishes the build as configured in the current drop-down menu for Build Configurations.  When I used the "old fashioned" cloud services, the publish profile included a build configuration.

This is kind of a problem for me, because, while I don't make a mistake in selecting the publish profile, it's quite easy to forget to set the correct build configuration beforehand.

So, is there a way to select a publish profile designed for a specific build configuration?

I'm not looking to automatically pick a publish profile.  What I want is, when I do pick a publish profile, that a specific build configuration is used for it.

Answer (score 3):

- If you're talking about your local dev cluster:

No. You need to switch the local dev cluster from 1 to 5 nodes or v.v. and change the bld configuration accordingly.

- If not:

I recommend you do not publish from VS to production cluster directly, but rely on a CI/CD pipeline instead.
For example look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-service-fabric), that explains how to set up such a pipeline in Azure DevOps (VSTS). In the release pipeline definition, you'd specify which publish profile should be deployed.

Among many other advantages, using this approach allows you to collaborate on a solution, have reviews and tests on your code before it's committed, built and deployed. This lowers the chances of deploying incorrect artifacts to the cluster.

If you require the ability to publish from your dev box, look at using a PowerShell script to build and package your solution and deploy the application package.

Comment: Not the local cluster.  I can't get that up and running, anyhow, but that's a different issue. Yes, you're absolutely right.  I should.  And, I will.  But, at the moment, I'm a one-man show and I'd like to solve this specific issue. Thanks for the link.  I'll be reading it.

Comment: Also, it's not the publish profile that's giving me problems.  There doesn't seem to be a way to connect a publish profile to a build configuration.  That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I see, good. You could use powershell to deploy with an explicit profile instead of using the publish button. https://github.com/vturecek/service-fabric-xray/blob/master/src/xray/Scripts/Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1

Comment: Ah!  Now we're getting somewhere.  Thanks!  I did look at that file and just missed it.  I think that script is executed after the build, though.. right?  Ideally, it would also build the correct configuration. Perhaps I can set ApplicationPackagePath in the ApplicationParameters xml file.

Comment: You could call msbuild to compile and package your solution and pass the output as an argument to the `Deploy-FabricApplication`

Comment: Yes.  I was just looking at that.  I can also customize the PublishProfile to add a configuration parameter and have the deployment script perform the build before it deploys.  VS ends up building twice, but that's a minor issue.